# CSS elements not aligned as expected with float: right

Tags: html, css, django

Social Media Platform: I am trying to get the image to line up above the sent message as you would have it in most standard DMs:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyO2b.png)

But for some reason, my images stick to the right side of the chat box: [without CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7c8i.png)

When I add `float: right;` to my CSS the image and the text layer horizontally in a strange manner: [image: with CSS]

Ideally, the image should be on the same side as the texts from the person who sent the image and should be just above the message that was attached to the image (as is commonplace).

`style.css`:

```
.sent-message {
        background-color: #d7a5eb;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 25%;
        float: right;
}

.received-message {
        background-color: #cc64c3;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
}

.message-receiver-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: auto;
}

.message-image-received {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
}

.message-image-sent {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
}
```

`thread.html`:

```
    {% for message in message_list %}
    <div class="row">
        {% if message.sender_user == request.user %}
        <div class="col-md-12 my-1">
            {% if message.image %}
            <div>
                <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image-sent" />
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="sent-message my-3">
                <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            {% elif message.receiver_user == request.user %}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {% if message.image %}
                <div class="message-receiver-container ms-auto">
                     <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image-received" />
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="received-message my-3">
                    <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %} 


    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-md-12 p-3 shadow-sm">
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'create-message' thread.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form | crispy }}
                
                <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
                    <button btn btn-light type="submit">Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you provided a working sample, but I think you might need to wrap your image and text in another div which you can then apple `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to -- take a look at the snippet below

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0 }
* { box-sizing: border-box }

#messages {
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  max-width: calc( (100% / 3) * 2 );
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.message.from {
  --color: #d7a5eb;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 3rem;
}
.message.to {
  --color: #cc64c3;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.message::before {
  background-color: var(--color);
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(0.625rem);
}
.message.from::before {
  left: 0.5rem;
}
.message.to::before {
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.message .img {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.message .img img { display: block }

.message .txt {
  background-color: var(--color);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.message.hasTxt.hasImg .img { border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0 }
.message.hasTxt.hasImg .txt { border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem }
```

```html
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message from hasImg hasTxt">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=1">
    </div>
    <div class="txt">
      Commodo erat curae integer elit adipiscing in a vestibulum enim enim habitasse a tempus id iaculis inceptos sagittis montes faucibus.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message from hasTxt">
    <div class="txt">
      Inceptos sagittis montes faucibus.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message to hasTxt">
    <div class="txt">
      Commodo erat curae integer elit adipiscing in a vestibulum enim enim habitasse a tempus id iaculis inceptos sagittis montes faucibus.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message to hasTxt">
    <div class="txt">
      Integer elit adipiscing in a vestibulum enim.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message to hasImg">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500?random=2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message from hasTxt">
    <div class="txt">
      CURAE INTEGER!!!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding that and it hasn't changed the issue. I'll insert some code to try a working example.

Answer (score 0):

For a working example:

`thread.html`:

```
> {% extends 'landing/base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
> 
> {% block content %}
> 
> <div class="container">
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="card col-md-12 mt-5 p-3 shadow-sm">
>             {% if thread.receiver == request.user %}
>                 <h5><h5><a href="{% url 'profile' thread.user.profile.pk %}"><img class="rounded-circle post-img"
> height="50" width="50" src="{{ thread.user.profile.picture.url }}"
> /></a> @{{ thread.user }}</h5>
>             {% else %}
>                 <h5>@{{ thread.receiver }}</h5>
>             {% endif %}
>         </div>
>     </div>
> 
>     {% if message_list.all.count == 0 %}
>     <div class="row my-5">
>         <div class="col-md-12">
>             <p class="empty-text">No messages yet.</p>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     {% endif %}
> 
>     {% for message in message_list %}
>     <div class="row">
>         {% if message.sender_user == request.user %}
>         <div class="col-md-12 my-1">
>             {% if message.image %}
>             <div class="message-sender-container ms-auto">
>                 <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image-sent" />
>             </div>
>             {% endif %}
>             <div class="sent-message my-3">
>                 <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>             {% elif message.receiver_user == request.user %}
>             <div class="col-md-12">
>                 {% if message.image %}
>                 <div class="message-receiver-container ms-auto">
>                      <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image-received" />
>                 </div>
>                 {% endif %}
>                 <div class="received-message my-3">
>                     <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>             {% endif %}
>         </div>
>     {% endfor %} 
> 
> 
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="card col-md-12 p-3 shadow-sm">
>             <form method="POST" action="{% url 'create-message' thread.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>                 {% csrf_token %}
>                 {{ form | crispy }}
>                 
>                 <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
>                     <button btn btn-light type="submit">Send Message</button>
>                 </div>
>             </form>
>         </div>
>     </div> </div>
> 
> {% endblock content %}
```

`style.css`:

```
.sent-message {
        background-color: #d7a5eb;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 25%;
        float: right;
}

.received-message {
        background-color: #cc64c3;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 25%;

}

.message-receiver-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 0;
}

.message-sender-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: auto;

}


.message-image-received {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;

}

.message-image-sent {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
        display: flex; 
        flex-direction: column;
}
```

`base.html`:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src ="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1d71f92e0a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Academicie</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/social.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know that a lot of the stuff included in the code here required something to be linked through in order for it to work (e.g. user profile URLs, profile pictures, message image urls) so please let me know what else I need to add to make the worked example function :)